# Dropdown values customization in NetSuite

Tags: customization, netsuite

There is a custom record type configured in NS. It has a name and a free-form text field called full_name. Name is a standard field, full_name is a custom field. There is another record type which has a field of type List/Record with the previous type. On the form this field is present as drop-down. The drop-down show names of records. The goal is to show full names instead of names in the drop-down. Is it possible to mark somehow full_name field so it is available in the drop-down view instead of just name? Any ideas how to achieve this with NS?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact needs, it may make sense to add another custom field to the record containing your drop down. You can source this field from the full_name field on the custom record. This field does not need to store the value if it's only for display purposes.

1. Add a new field to the record containing the drop down
2. Set the type to be text
3. Name it appropriately
4. Under the 'Sourcing and Filtering' tab, set the source by field to the drop down

Answer (score 0):

A field with type List/Record type can only show standard Name field. However, you can create a custom field dynamically on before record load of a user event script. Check the nlobjForm.addField. Please keep in mind that the value of it will not be saved. Saving the value is another story.